# Two iPhones, buth synced but with different contacts

Tags: iphone, ios, data-synchronization, contacts

I have two iPhones and I would like to have them nicely synced calendar and task, but to keep different contacts. One is an office phone and I would like not to have my private numbers etc. Currently, on my old phone I have mail + contacts synced with Google, and Calendars, Reminders on iCloud, same as on my MacBook Air.

Can I sync some data but not all of it?

Answer (score 1):

Only way I can think is to set up as 2 [or more] groups - so the contacts are there but not in your 'current' list.

That's how I logically separate my business from personal contacts.

Uncheck the groups you don't want to see on each phone

[image]         [image]

Answer (score 0):

Sign up for a free iCloud account to store your private contacts.

Calendars and tasks can be synchronized to both devices and only turn on contact syncing for the one device